# Android SDK Managers - Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, sdk

I have installed SDK managers for API levels (15,21, 22,26). If SDK Managers is just for testing the app, can i delete the API level packages that i have installed and install other API levels to test those API's as well? And Is it going to affect how the app will work?  I want to delete the already installed packages because i have already tested them.

Comment: The Android SDK Manager allows you to select which packages you want to install.The SDK Platform for a given API level allows you to compile against that version of Android. Refer for more information this link : http://www.themethodology.net/2015/02/android-sdk-manager-setup-for.html?m=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Android Dashboard:

https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

You can see the respective distribution percentages for devices around the world. This means that it can help you choose what API levels you want to support in your application.

The SDK Manager is used as a means of downloading and managing the Android SDK and other tooling. The APIs that you install will allow you to develop for that version of Android.

I believe your question refers to the Emulator Images provided in the SDK Manager. These take up quite a bit of space on your computer and you can install/uninstall these whenever you want as they are simply images that emulate the respective API level with optional Google APIs if wanted.

To answer your question:

1. There's no need to uninstall the actual `Android SDK Platform X` where X is the API level. These are small packages compared to `System Images`
2. You can feel free to uninstall any `System Image` that you are no longer using if you had already tested the application on that version. The only note of caution here is that they are large and might take a bit of time to install again. I typically keep one from each of the following API levels of emulators (19->26)
3. As long as you are only uninstalling `System Image` items and not the `Android SDK Platform`, this will not affect your application in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking API 22 as an example. Below is the items for API 22 that is available in Android SDK Manager:
[image]

**SDK Platform**: You need this when your project you set this as your project's compile version. In the following case, you only need Android 7.1 SDK Platform
[image]

**Other ** System Image**: Needed when you want to create Android Emulator

**Google APIs**: Can be delete anytime

**Sources for Android SDK**: Can be delete anytime